Quotients of the Hilbert space
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with a biinvariant metric.
Note that $G\times G$ acts isometrically on $G$ from left and right.
Consider the quotient $D=G/H$ by a closed subgroup $H\le G\times G$;
if $D$ can be obtained this way, then it will be called a double quotient of $G$.
Now suppose a group $L$ acts isometrically on the Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$.
Assume that the quotient $\mathbb{H}/L$ is isometric to a compact Riemannian manifold $M$.

Is it true that $M$ is isometric to a double quotient of a compact Lie group?

Comments

At the moment, I do not know if $M$ is analytic.

Any double quotient of a compact Lie group is a quotient of the Hilbert space by an isometric action (see “Submanifold geometry in symmetric spaces” by C.-L. Terng and G. Thorbergsson). In particular, the standard sphere can be obtained this way.



You make no assumptions about $L$ (abstract group, topological group, Lie group …), or about smoothness of the action?

@LSpice just a subgoup of group of isometries, but you can get something about this action since the quotient is compact Hausdorff space.
